# How can I get the content from this string separately?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$message[0]['body'] = "b<br /><br />Rajesh wrote:<br /><br />a<br /><br />Raven Lexy wrote:<br /><br />ok<br /><br />Raven Lexy wrote:<br /><br />12body of the message<br /><br />Artin wrote:<br />body of the message<br /><br />Raven Lexy wrote:<br /><br />1body of the message";
```

the content before wrote: is the main string but exactly before wrote: there is member name  and before member name its message , Now I want this message and member name is separate array , How can i achieve this?

please help,
Thanks

Comment: Pretty nasty job you will have to do there, but if the structure oh html don't change you can brake parts by double `<br/><br/>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$parts = explode('<br /><br />', $message[0]['body']);
$authors = array();
$messages = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    if($i & 1) $authors[] = $parts[$i];
    else $messages[] = $parts[$i];
}

var_dump($authors);
var_dump($messages);
```

But the string must begin with Author name.
`$i & 1` checks whether `$i` is odd (=1) or even (=0).